# PHP Counter Improvement

Tags: php

Currently I'm displaying a news feed from an XML file and using a counter to limit the number of news articles that are displayed. But I'm unsure if this is the best way to do it.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
function get_news($feed) {

$xml = new SimpleXmlElement(uwe_get_file($feed));
$counter = 0;
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) {
    echo '<a href="' . $item->link . '" target="_blank">' . $item->title . '</a><br />' . '<i>' . $item->description . '</i>' . '<strong>' . $item->pubDate . '</strong>' . '<br />' . '<br />';
    ++$counter;
    if ($counter == 5) {
        break;
    }
}
}

?>
```

Any suggestions on how I could improve this counter?

Comment: You could shorten your `++$counter;` and `if($counter == 5)` line to `if (++$counter == 5)`

Comment: You could shorten it by one line like this `if(++$counter === 5) {`

Comment: Your loop is about as efficient as it will get, unless your XML file contains radically more than 5 elements, such as 2,000.  Your reader is DOM-based and a SAX-style parser may save you from scanning the whole input.  That is about the only optimization I can think of.

Comment: @Graham The counter is working fine just thought that there may have been a better way of coding it.

Comment: I'd use printf($fmt) instead of `echo this . that . the_other`.  But unless there's more than one way to skin any cat, and whatever method is going to be most readable in 6 or 12 months is probably the one you should pick.  Supporting your code is always more work than writing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming standard key values (0-based integers). You could change the loop to:

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
    $item = $xml->channel->item[$i];
    echo '<a href="' . $item->link . '" target="_blank">' . $item->title . '</a><br />' . '<i>' . $item->description . '</i>' . '<strong>' . $item->pubDate . '</strong>' . '<br />' . '<br />';
}
```

But I can't see it performing any better, just less code.

Answer (score 2):

That's a perfectly good and valid way of doing it. Personally, I'd write `$counter++` rather than `++$counter`, but that's just my personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `for` loop you could get rid of the `if($counter == 5)` check:

```
function get_news($feed) {

   $xml = new SimpleXmlElement(uwe_get_file($feed));
   $count = count($xml->channel->item);
   for ($x = 0; ($x < $count && $x <= 5); $x++) {
     echo '<a href="' . $xml->channel->item[$x]->link . '" target="_blank">' . $xml->channel->item[$x]->title . '</a><br />' . '<i>' . l->channel->item[$x]->description . '</i>' . '<strong>' . l->channel->item[$x]->pubDate . '</strong>' . '<br />' . '<br />';
    }
 }
```